# Simple way to use "Students who haven't done the homework."

Tags: sentence-construction

I am a teacher and I want to know how many students have not done the homework.

> Those students who haven't done the homework. Please stand up.

Is this sentence fine?

Is there a simple way to say this?
Should I use simple past instead of perfect?

Comment: You need a comma, not a period. But I'd be embarrassed for those students who had to stand up.

Comment: I would do it the other way, having the ones who did it raise their hands. Standing up is for reciting. Or if you simply collect the homework instead of depending on their words, you'll know and they won't be embarrassed in public.

Comment: "Please stand up if you have [not] done the homework."

Answer (score 1):

Homework is not a countable noun, so you have to say:

- **the** homework **assignment**
- **their** homework
- **your** homework

So you might say:

> Please stand up if you have not done your homework.
>
> Please stand up if you have not done the homework assignment.
>
> Anyone who has not done their homework, please stand up.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma, as you're giving an instruction to someone, such as "David, please tidy your room."

The audience is "Those students who haven't done the homework", so swap that in to get "Students who haven't done the homework, please stand up.", or as a request, "Could those students who haven't done the homework please stand up."